# MultiUserChat always returns not connected although I am online in the server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am having a strange problem. I have a XMPPTCPCONNECTION set up to a remote server. I then created a chatroom in the server from the smack library. 
Now when I join the room, I can see that I am online in the server and the spark client also shows me online. However, multiuserchat.isJoined() returns false. I have been having this issue for a week. Help needed.
I had posted a similar question but no one answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902262/no-response-from-openfire-server-although-connected

Comment: I understand you and I am also facing same problem right now. I am trying to resolve the issue. :) When you get the solution please share it

Comment: ok..are you using the same version of smack... 4.2 alpaha release>?

Comment: I am using smack 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

OK. the problem was that the XMPP server does not do the address normalization. My MUC JID in the server was saathi@conference.service but I used Saathi@conference.service . All I had to do was change it to lowercase.